# WCF DataContract vs DataContract Interface

Tags: c#, wcf

New to WCF.

Can DataContact class inherit from Interface ?

eg:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = ...........)]
public class VesselSequence : IVesselSequence
{

    [DataMember]
    public int AllocationId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ScenarioName { get; set; }
}

interface VesselSequence : IVesselSequence
{
    public int AllocationId { get; set; }
    public string ScenarioName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = ...........)]
public class VesselSequence : IVesselSequence
{
    [DataMember]
    public int AllocationId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ScenarioName { get; set; }
}

interface IVesselSequence
{
    int AllocationId { get; set; }
    string ScenarioName { get; set; }
}
```

You can't do this, sadly:

```
public class VesselSequence : IVesselSequence
{
    public int AllocationId { get; set; }
    public string ScenarioName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = ...........)]
interface IVesselSequence
{
    [DataMember]
    int AllocationId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    string ScenarioName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

sure it can, but keep in mind if you are returning the interface type you have to define the KnownTypes attribute for deserialization engine, so it could deserialize your sent interface at the other end.