# Is it possible to use an interface type as parameter type in a WCF operation?

Tags: c#, interface, communication, wcf

There's some interface:

```
public interface IMessage
{
    string Content;
    Person Sender;
}

public class Priv : IMessage
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Person Sender { get; set; }
    private int whatever;
}

public class Publ : IMessage
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Person Sender { get; set; }
    private DateTime something;
}
```

Is it possible to use in wcf service `IMessage` instance? 
Like `void SomeMethod(IMessage toSend)`?

Comment: Sure you can, just make the interface a `DataContract`! Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090736/wcf-datacontract-vs-datacontract-interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You have to tell the Service the list of expected implementations you will send by using the [`KnownTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) attribute